# Jruby socket error

Tags: sockets, jruby

I'm useing netbeans and Jruby. When I want to build a project I got the following message:
SEVERE: library `socket' could not be loaded: java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  java/net/URLClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "org/jruby/ext/socket/RubySocket"

Can anybody help to me what could be the problem ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue with jdk6u18 or higher.  The workaround currently is to downgrade to jdk6u17.  You can find more information here https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6923688

I'd highly suggest voting so that Oracle fixes it.  We're already at u20 and they still haven't addressed the problem.

Comment: so how does one "downgrade to jdk6u17"?